# Why can't I append a String to a NSURL?

Tags: swift, nsurl, writetofile

Appending the .txt file component to the URL path doesn't work:

```
var error:NSError?
let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let docURL = manager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain:.UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL:nil, create:true, error:&error)
docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("/RicFile.txt") <-- doesn't work
```

via debugger:

```
file:///Users/Ric/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
<device id>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<app id>/Documents/
```

Writing a String using **docURL** to a file doesn't work because of the missing file name.

Reason (via error):

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. Is a directory"

**So Question: Why doesn't the following work?**

```
docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("/RicFile.txt")
```

Answer (score 19):

`URLByAppendingPathComponent:` doesn't mutate the existing `NSURL`, it creates a new one. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/URLByAppendingPathComponent:):

> URLByAppendingPathComponent: Returns a new URL made by appending a
>   path component to the original URL.

You'll need to assign the return value of the method to something. For example:

```
let directoryURL = manager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain:.UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL:nil, create:true, error:&error)
let docURL = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("/RicFile.txt")
```

Even better would be to use `NSURL(string:String, relativeTo:NSURL)`:

```
let docURL = NSURL(string:"RicFile.txt", relativeTo:directoryURL)
```

Comment: `NSURL(string:String, relativeTo:NSURL)` will also work.  It is even arguably more correct if your appended URL string may not be a relative path. as it will correctly deal with the stringUrl being interpreted relative to the base url instead of just appending it.

Comment: Hmm, I overlooked that one. I'll update the question, thanks!

Comment: You're actually changing the url to be absolute (starting it with /) where the original question seems to be relative.  I've edited your answer to be more inline with that.

Answer (score 0):

With the update to the Swift language, the suggested call to manager.URLForDirectory(...) no longer works because the call can throw (an exception). The specific error is "Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled". The throw can be handled with the following code:

```
    let directoryURL: NSURL?
    do
    {
        directoryURL = try manager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentationDirectory,
                            inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
    }
    catch _
    {
        print("Error: call to manager.URLForDirectory(...) threw an exception")
    }
```